# dplyr: Pass grouped data to a function in summarize()

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a problem with dplyr I often stumble over. Let's consider the following code:

```
foo <- function (x, aux) {...}

auxcols <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
group_by(iris, Species) %>%
  summarize(f = foo(Sepal.Length, .[, auxcols]))
```

NOTE: `auxcols` is not known in advance.

Here `aux` is receives the full ungrouped data. This is never what I want.

How would I have to change the call to `summarize()` so that `aux` contains only the data from the group that is about to be summarized?

Comment: use `cur_data()` instead of the `.`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes! You are my hero. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Onyambu provided the correct solution.

```
group_by(iris, Species) %>%
  summarize(f = foo(Sepal.Length, cur_data()[, auxcols]))
```

So easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `foo` such that it receives the two columns as two separate variables, as such:

```
foo <- function(length, sepal, petal) {
   ## if you really, really need to process it as a data.frame, just re-create it:
  aux <- data.frame(Sepal.Width=sepal, Petal.width=petal)
}

group_by(iris, Species) %>% summarise(f= foo(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Width))
```

Comment: No, that's not possible because I don't know the columns in advance. They are passed as characters. I'll adjust the description.